# Can't Make Sense of Blazor/Mono Compile Error?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm working on a web assembly-based Blazor project and am running into an error that is fairly verbose and I can't quite figure out what the issue is other than it relates to dependencies.

Have I done something wrong here, is this a problem with one of the Blazor packages? What's the right action to take to resolve this?

I've updated my Blazor server project to ASP.NET Core 3.0.

The error code is MSB3073.

The description is:

`The command "dotnet "C:\Users\twhite\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview1.19508.20\targets\../tools/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build.dll" resolve-dependencies "C:\EpicSource\Tools\TaylorTest\TaylorTest\TaylorTest.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\TaylorTest.Client.dll" --references "C:\EpicSource\Tools\TaylorTest\TaylorTest\TaylorTest.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\resolve-dependencies.txt" --base-class-library "C:\Users\twhite\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview1.19503.1\build\netstandard1.0\../../tools/mono/bcl/" --base-class-library "C:\Users\twhite\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.1.0-preview1.19503.1\build\netstandard1.0\../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" --output "C:\EpicSource\Tools\TaylorTest\TaylorTest\TaylorTest.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\resolved.assemblies.txt"" exited with code -2147450730. TaylorTest.Client   C:\Users\twhite\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview1.19508.20\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets`

I've looked around on Blazor's Github listing and found one seemingly similar issue ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8158)), but still don't understand the error, and also don't understand how to resolve this issue.

Any ideas as to what this issue is? It seems to be some kind of dependency issue that was introduced while upgrading to various versions.

I've tried reverting to v.3.0.0-preview9.19465.2 which seems to resolve the issue. I am prevented from upgrading to v3.1.* preview versions though.

Comment: "I've updated my Blazor server project to ASP.NET Core 3.0" - but the error mentions 3.1 a lot. Better recheck all your versions. If you can't solve it, post your .csproj and also the exact version of VS.

Comment: I updated the "Server" project to 3.0, the "Client" project I updated to the latest pre-release to 3.1 (hence the errors).

Like I mentioned I've been able to "get the error to go away" by reverting the Client project DLLs to v.3.0.0-preview9.19465.2, but cannot upgrade to the latest pre-release version.

Comment: You do need VS2019 preview.